# Relaunch an existing iOS app on App Store after changing the signing certificate?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, mobile-application

Apologies in advance if this is a bad question though I really need to understand this. I got to know that we can resign any .IPA file without having the need of code. Following are the links with the solution.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71343 
https://coderwall.com/p/dgdgeq/how-to-re-sign-ios-builds

This brings a question to my mind that by doing this anyone can relaunch any existing app. Let’s say, I download the .IPA file of any famous app like “Angry Birds”. Now using the above mentioned process, I can resign the app using my certificates and launch it in my name. I am sure this won't be possible at all and I am missing something big. 
Can anybody please help me understand how it works ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apple actually checks if the Binary of an app matches any other that already exists on the store.. I have a coworker that has been rejected for this before and he had to explain to them that it's not possible for it to match so they can verify again.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Does this mean that if someone uses enterprise portal instead of app store to launch app, then this is doable. One can launch somebody's app in his/her name on enterprise portal ? I believe Apple can't check on the enterprise portal.

Comment: I'm not sure about enterprise stuff, but yes you can re-sign any IPA.. After all, this is how Jailbroken AppStores work..

Comment: sure. Thanks Brandon.

Comment: For the sake of discussion, this brings another query to my mind. If I have multiple clients who need similar kind of app with minor changes, will apple reject all the apps because all apps would be having similar kind of binaries with minor changes.? Please do share your thoughts and lets hear from others as well. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the audience for the app. Apple has cracked down on developers providing slight variations of the same app in the past. Your scenario might be better served by a B2B app or an enterprise distribution.